# Buy bacteria for experiment?

Tags: bacteriology

Where can I buy paracoccus denitrificans? I need it for an experiment. I cannot find online where I can purchase this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATCC- you can get most bacterial strains and cell lines there.

Find *P. denitrificans* [here](http://www.atcc.org/products/all/13543.aspx):

www.atcc.org/products/all/13543.aspx

Comment: You said see this but didn't link to anything. Did you mean to include a link?

Comment: yep.. it didnt work.. see the edit

Comment: Sorry about that. I have accepted it.